# How to run Jersey 2 and Jetty

Tags: jersey, jetty-8

Trying out the latest Jersey-2 release. I need to run it with Jetty embedded. I have a resource that worked fine with Jersey 1.15. Tried the following code bu can't reach my Resource.

```
ServletContextHandler sh = new ServletContextHandler();
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.packages("com");
sh.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/*");
```

The above Handler is then being set into a Jetty Server instance.

I am using Jetty 8.17.

Any Ideas?